# Div html from code behind is not displaying C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm trying to generate Accordion Pane from code behind. Somehow, the accordion is not display out. I have a Menu.aspx which is in the AccordionMenu ContentPlaceHolder and also a div. In my code behind, i try to create accordion pane with the div. Below are my codes.

**Menu.aspx**

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="AccordionMenu" runat="Server">

<div id="divMenu" style="width: 241px" runat="server"></div>
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // Create Accordion Pane Header Content
    divMenu.InnerHtml = "<div class='tab_container' id='tab_container'>";

    foreach (SiteMapNode node in SiteMap.RootNode.ChildNodes)
    {
        // Header
        //Check whether is first node
        if (SiteMap.RootNode.ChildNodes.Count == 0)
        {
            // Create header html
            divMenu.InnerHtml += "<h3 class='d_active tab_drawer_heading' rel='" + node.Title + "'>" + node.Title + "</h3>";          
        }
        else
        {
            divMenu.InnerHtml += "<h3 class='tab_drawer_heading' rel='" + node.Title + "'>" + node.Title + "</h3>";
        }

        // Create header html
        divMenu.InnerHtml += "div id='" + node.Title + "' class='tab_content' style='display: block;'>";

        // Content
        foreach (SiteMapNode child in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            // Check Role Access Right
            if (CheckRolePermission(ConstantValues.MAINTENANCEMODE_VIEW, GetFunctionNameByTitle(child.Title)))
            {
                // Create content html
                divMenu.InnerHtml += "<p>" + child.Title + "</p>";
                divMenu.InnerHtml += "</div>";
            }
        }
    }

    divMenu.InnerHtml += "</div>";

}
```

**HTML ONLY - Working**

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="content-container">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="tab_container" id="tab_container">
              <h3 class="d_active tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab1">Tab 1</h3>
              <div id="tab1" class="tab_content" style="display: block;">
                <p>Content 1</p>
              </div>
              <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab2">Tab 2</h3>
              <div id="tab2" class="tab_content" style="display: none;">
                <p>Content 2</p>
              </div>
              <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab3">Tab 3</h3>
              <div id="tab3" class="tab_content" style="display: none;">
                <p>Content 3</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <script src="Menu/Js/menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </td>
        <td/>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Any specific reason for not using nested repeaters (`<asp:Repeater />`)?

Comment: i was using ajax accordion pane. Now, my client requested to make the website mobile responsive, i replace the ajax accordion pane with CSS

Comment: when you do this kind of solution (which i would recommend you to do) , you should use a <asp:panel> instead of a <div runat="server">   , asp:panel generates a  html Div.

Comment: Can you post the rendered markup? Does it render the `<div />` at all? Could it be related to `css`?

Comment: @scheien its not entering the page load in the Menu.aspx.cs

Comment: I try to create a table with dummy data and comment out the divMenu.  The table is not shown as well. The page seems not working.

Answer (score 1):

You missed starting tag of div. try this one.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // Create Accordion Pane Header Content
    divMenu.InnerHtml = "<div class='tab_container' id='tab_container'>";

    foreach (SiteMapNode node in SiteMap.RootNode.ChildNodes)
    {
        // Header
        //Check whether is first node
        if (SiteMap.RootNode.ChildNodes.Count == 0)
        {
            // Create header html
            divMenu.InnerHtml += "<h3 class='d_active tab_drawer_heading' rel='" + node.Title + "'>" + node.Title + "</h3>";          
        }
        else
        {
            divMenu.InnerHtml += "<h3 class='tab_drawer_heading' rel='" + node.Title + "'>" + node.Title + "</h3>";
        }

        // Create header html
        divMenu.InnerHtml += "<div id='" + node.Title + "' class='tab_content' style='display: block;'>";

        // Content
        foreach (SiteMapNode child in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            // Check Role Access Right
            if (CheckRolePermission(ConstantValues.MAINTENANCEMODE_VIEW, GetFunctionNameByTitle(child.Title)))
            {
                // Create content html
                divMenu.InnerHtml += "<p>" + child.Title + "</p>";
            }
        }

        divMenu.InnerHtml += "</div>";
    }

    divMenu.InnerHtml += "</div>";

}
```

Comment: still not displaying =(

Comment: when i debug, it is not entering the page_load. Any idea to enter the page_load function so I can check the generated html output?